# How to add Activity Tag(s)

Tags: activities, tags

How do you add a new Activity tag(s)?

I can see how you add a tag at /civicrm/tag but when I add one it doesn't show up as a option when creating an activity? Is there somewhere else that you add a tag that specifically for activities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New tags are for contacts by default, but you can change that by setting "Used For" activities instead of contacts:

[image: New Tag]

Comment: Thanks so much!